# CodeBat Python - Logic 1 - where is the error in my logic?

Tags: python, logic, truthiness

The question, my answer, and the output is screenshotted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJKRg.png)

Constraints:

**`0`**=no ticket
**`1`**=small ticket
**`2`**=big ticket.

If speed is 60 or less, the result is 0. If speed is between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is 1. If speed is 81 or more, the result is 2. Unless it is your birthday -- on that day, your speed can be 5 higher in all cases.

My Code:

```
def caught_speeding(speed, is_birthday):
  
  if speed > 80 or (speed > 85 and is_birthday):
    return 2
  return int((60 < speed <= 80) or (65 < speed <= 85 and is_birthday))
```

`caught_speeding(65, True)` gives 1 but should be **`0`**

`caught_speeding(85, True)` gives 2 but should be **`1`**

the other tests are ok. When I trace the code I cant seem to find the error

Answer (score 1):

For `caught_speeding(65, True)`, the first condition is false so it falls through to the `return` statement.  In that case, `(60 < speed <= 80)` is true, since 65 falls within that range.  The other condition doesn't matter since it's joined with an `or`, so it's effectively doing `return int(True)` which is `1`.

For `caught_speeding(85, True)`, the `speed > 80` condition is true, since 85 is greater than 80.  Again, the other condition doesn't matter since it's joined with an `or`, so it executes the `return 2` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can come up with a one-liner solution using the following logic, subtracting 5 from *`speed`* when *`is_birthday`* parameter gets a **`True`** value:

```
def caught_speeding(speed, is_birthday):
  if is_birthday:
      speed -= 5
  return 0 if speed < 60 else 1 if speed <= 80 and speed >= 61 else 2 if speed >= 81 else 0

print(caught_speeding(81, 0))
print(caught_speeding(65, True))
print(caught_speeding(85, True))
```

**Output:**

```
2
0
1
```

Comment: what is this syntax called:
return 0 ... else 1 ... else 2 ... else 0

I've never seen this before, specifically the else parts of the line

Comment: Doesn't answer the question and is pretty long. Do you think a speed of 80.9 shall get unpunished?

Comment: @kelly-bundy You're right, the solution is a little bit long. Also, a speed of 80.9 receives a result of only 1 because that's the rule it has to obey.

Comment: "little bit" as in the return expression is about three times as long as necessary :-). I meant 80.9 not on the birthday. You return 0 then, not 1. That's why I said unpunished.

Comment: @kelly-bundy Ok, I completely forgot about the birthday component. Thanks for remembering. I will update the answer

Comment: Wait, what? Your birthday handling seems fine...

Comment: To be clear: I think the speed is given as integer, so 80.9 is invalid. Otherwise the original spec is incomplete. It's just that your checking of lower bounds and your final `else 0` suggest that you think that that `0` can be reached, i.e., that non-integers in the gaps *are* allowed.